# pre-commit (tool) in jenkins pipelines, nitialize and stop build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

[pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com) is a great tool and id like to incorporate it into jenkins pipelines just to make sure someone didn't try to skip it during committing to the repo.

so my questions are:

- what are the best practices to initialize pre-commit? (just initialize it as i would in the repo? the website offers examples for some other CI integrations but not jenkins)
- how can i say to jenkins to stop the build if any of the tests performed by pre-commit fails? (exit code? which one would be `success` or `fail`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as [the docs indicate](https://pre-commit.com/#usage-in-continuous-integration) the best way to run `pre-commit` in a CI system is with `pre-commit run`, usually `pre-commit run --all-files --show-diff-on-failure`

this will exit nonzero which should fail your pipeline as desired

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit

Comment: TY! `--show-diff-on-failure` is just what i needed. i can work with that